Can/should you use th:attr with th:insert/replace in thymleaf? Fragments with elements whose attributes can be dynamically set
I like the principle of DRY (Don't repeat yourself) in coding. And while I continue to learn thymeleaf, I am running into this error I am unable to resolve.
So the general idea is as follows, I want to construct fragments with elements whose attributes can be dynamically set.
Here is a simple example:
<input th:fragment="input (inputAttributes)" th:attr="${inputAttributes}"/>

In other words, a fragment that accepts parameter(s) that will behave as the place to put attributes and their associated values.
However, when I attempted to use such fragments, I keep getting parsing errors:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "${inputAttributes}"
Here is example of me calling the fragment:
<div th:replace="inputfragments.html :: input(inputAttributes='id=username, name=username')"></div>

I know I can replace this particular example with something like
<input th:attr='id=username, name=username'/>

But the answer to the question serves a greater purpose for instances with complex fragments and the necessity for dynamically set attributes...
